# Is one allowed to talk in a shower?

Tags: halacha, speech-talking, showering-bathing

While in a shower is one allowed to talk to someone else (not about Torah - "regular" talking)?

I understand that talking in a bathroom is normally not permitted. Is a shower the same or different?

Answer (score 9):

See [SA OC Siman 84](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.84.1?lang=bi) where it is clear that talking itself is allowed in a bathhouse, the restrictions are only to greeting with the word Sholom and speaking Torah etc.

> אם מותר לקרות במרחץ ובו סעיף אחד:
> מרחץ חדש שלא רחצו בו מות' לקרות בו ובישן בבית החיצון שכל העומדי' שם לבושים מותר ובאמצעי שקצת העומדים שם לבושים וקצת ערומים יש שם שאילת שלום אבל לא ק"ש ותפלה: הגה ומותר להרהר שם בדברי תורה [ר"ן פ"ק דשבת ופרק כל הצלמים] ובפנימי שכלם עומדים שם ערומים אפי' שאלת שלום אסור [ואסור לענות אמן בבית המרחץ] [ר"ן פ' כירה]:

Comment: What about nowadays when they are connected?

Comment: I would assume that the talking in a bathroom prohibition is limited to when one who is doing his 'needs', and I take that from the fact we see people go into the bathroom to get things while talking to others, and more important proof is from SA OC (43:5) that some say that going into a Bais Hakisay Kovuah with Tefilin is allowed if he's not doing his needs. Also see Mishnah Berurah (3:4) and Sha'arei Teshuva there #2.

Comment: I don't think you're right on that one. I've seen the Posekim discuss talking in the bathroom (not while using the bath) and they prohibit. They say it's less of a prohibiton than while using but nevertheless should be avoided.

Comment: @Hacham Gabriel Can you please supply sources, there is some type of imbalance on this forum that when you answer a question you're required to bring sources, but in comments against an answer you can get away with 'Reshonim say' 'posskim write' without any backup proof.

Comment: When someone writes a comment they're not "Paskening" (I know we're not Paskening Halacha LeMaaseh here but we are in own way) therefor they are allowed to write they're own opinion (this is my understanding).

Comment: And I do have a source(Yabia Omer vol. 8 Orah Haim Siman 1).

Comment: I don't have it and I can't find a link to it, the Aruch Hashulchan 3:3 writes ולא ידבר כשהוא נפנה. Also the Mechaber himself in 85:2 says it's allowed and the Achronim say it's Midas chassidus not to based on Sefer Chassidim 994.

Comment: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%94 I don't see that in the Mehaber.

Comment: אפילו להרהר בדברי תורה אסור בבית הכסא...
דברים של חול מותר לאמרם שם בלשון הקדש.

Comment: Oops, I thought that was part of the Rama. Nevertheless for some reason Hacham Dawid quotes his father saying that you shouldn't talk even before actually using the bathroom.

Comment: Because of Midas Chassidus but not Halacha.

Comment: When I looked in Yalkut Yosef and Halacha Berura 85 they both excluded Bet HaKise and only wrote Bet HaMehras. For some reason Hacham Dawid is Mahmir in the Bet HaMerhas.

Comment: Now look in Yalkut Yosef Siman 3:9&10 and in Piskei Teshuvos page 29 (I don't have Jalacha Berurah)

Comment: I read Siman 3:9-10 plenty of times and I don't see how it proves anything. I don't own Piske Teshuvot.